# How do I create a Ghost Boot CD?

Tags: windows, norton-ghost

For a previous job, my boss wanted to keep using Ghost and didn't want to switch to Clonezilla (which I recommend) but wanted a way to Ghost all machines and even future ones from one disk or CD.

So I need a Ghose Boot CD that not only clones all systems we have, but would be editable for future systems.

Comment: I changed your question, so now you can add your "answer" :-)

Answer (score 2):

Awhile back I wrote about this on my website and thought it could help others, so here it is:

http://www.webs05.com/2007/10/16/how-to-create-a-ghost-boot-cd.html

Just follow the steps in that link and you should be good to go. Keep in mind I really recommend Clonezilla for any imaging as the hardware support it has in the Linux Kernel is much more extensive than the simple Ghost CD. But I realize some IT shops cannot switch over for whatever reason and are stuck with Ghost. In that case I hope this helps!

Comment: Since this is the correct answer to your question, you should mark it "accepted".